# Android Kotlin editText Listener Question

Tags: android, kotlin, listener

I'm trying to program something where a user inputs a number into an editText field and it automatically has decimal places appended. I'm using `editText.setText` inside the listener, but find that the code crashes every time. Upon logging the value that I'm trying to edit, I found that the moment I change the editText field, `editText.setText` runs non-stop, which causes the program to crash. Below is my code:

```
val etTesting = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etTesting)
        etTesting.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (!s.isNullOrEmpty() && s.toString() != ".") {
                    val value = s.toString().toDouble()
                    val formatted = String.format("%.2f", value)
                    Log.i(TAG, "onTextChanged $formatted")
                    etTesting.setText(formatted)
                    etTesting.setSelection(formatted.length)
                }
            }
        })
```

I tried to use setText outside of the listener and it doesn't trigger a crash. It's only inside the listener. I'm guessing it has to do with the listener writing an updated value, seeing that it's updated again, and then goes through this sequence infinitely?

How is one supposed to use the listener to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a more general approach (instead of relying on filters, which aren't always enough for what you want to do) you could create some kind of `updating` flag in your `TextWatcher`:

```
object : TextWatcher {
    var updating = false

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        // skip reacting to the text change if it's caused by an internal update
        if (!updating) {
            updating = true
            // make changes to the text contents
            updating = false
        }
    }
}
```

Basically when `onTextChanged` fires, it checks to see if there's an internal update happening, and only proceeds if there isn't. First it sets that `updating` flag, and then updates the text, which immediately triggers the `TextWatcher` callbacks again.

Those calls are recursive, so your initial `onTextChanged` function won't complete until the triggered `onTextChanged` returns. And if that fires *another* `onTextChanged`, you end up with infinite nested function calls until you get a (heyo) stack overflow.

By using this flag, you short-circuit that behaviour. Because the first call sets that `updating` flag, the text change will trigger a second call, which sees that `updating` is *true*, and returns without making any changes. Then your first `onTextChanged` call will complete. And the last thing it does is set `updating` to *false* since the update process has finished, so it's ready to handle the next change.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will crash, because as soon as you format and set text, `onTextChanged` is called with new value and this is repeated infintely, so best option here would be to use `filters` and validate and return the text as you need, an example of how to use

```
etTesting.filters = arrayOf(object : InputFilter {
    override fun filter(
        input: CharSequence?,
        p1: Int,
        p2: Int,
        p3: Spanned?,
        p4: Int,
        p5: Int
    ): CharSequence =
        if (!input.isNullOrEmpty() && input.toString() != ".") {
            val value = input.toString().toDouble()
            String.format("%.2f", value)
        } else input?:""
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I've only just started playing with Android, so I haven't gotten to filters yet. I'll try this out as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will crash, because when you type something in the EditText, the addTextChangedListener will trigger and if you also use setText in your listener and it will trigger again and again, this will lead your app to crash, because it will repeat forever, Like you use a while loop.

Use the InputFilter interface to implement your own filtered CharSequence. Like this.

```
    val inputFilter = object : InputFilter {
        override fun filter(
            input: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Spanned?, p4: Int, p5: Int
        ): CharSequence {
            return if (!input.isNullOrEmpty() && input.isDigitsOnly() && input.toString() != ".") {
                val value = input.toString().toDouble()
                String.format("%.2f", value)
            } else {
                ""
            }
        }
    }

    etTesting.setFilters(arrayOf<InputFilter>(inputFilter))
```

Hope this would be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks Yousef, as with the above, I play around with input filters :)